# Errors when trying to compute the average

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to compute the average of the values from the .data section but I keep getting errors relating to the PC and another error for bad address in data/stack read. I'm not understanding how to fix the issue. I am a beginner working on this for an assignment and was hoping to get some help as to how to properly compute the average.

```
.data
one:    .byte 12
two:    .byte 97
three:  .byte 133
four:   .byte 82
five:   .byte 236

.text
main:
ori $8, $0, 0x5
ori $9, $0, 0
lui $10, 0x1000
lbu $11, one($10)    #get byte one
addu $12, $11, $9    #add byte one to $9
lbu $11, two($10)    #get byte two
addu $12, $11, $12   #add byte two to the sum
lbu $11, three($10)   #get byte 3
addu $12, $11, $12    #add byte 3 to the sum
lbu $11, four($10)    #get byte 4
addu $12, $11, $12    #add byte 4 to the sum
lbu $11, five($10)     #get byte 5
addu $12, $11, $12     #add byte 5 to the sum
divu $12, $8     #divide the sum by 5
mflo $13     #store the result in $13
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `jr $ra` at the bottom of your `main`, so even if the code was correct execution would fall off the end into garbage.

But also `one($register)` is a pseudo-instruction that will construct the full address of `one` plus the register value for the actual load or store.  Since you used `lui $10, 0x1000` manually (because MARS defaults to putting its data section at `0x10001000` or something, IIRC), your actual load address will be `0x1000 << 16` too high.

You want something like `%lo(one)($10)` but MARS doesn't have that: you have to either hard-code a number or just use `lbu $11, one` or `lbu $11, one($0)`

Or `la` the address of the start of the data into a register and then index everything relative to that.

IDK if there are any other bugs; you're missing a MCVE.